# how to increase Place Api request limit per day in android?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I enable billing in android Place api. Now I restrict key for 'Android'. With restriction place api has limit for request is 2400 requests/day.
without restriction it is works fine. How can I get more request limit with application restriction?

Place request is as below.

```
        List<Place.Field> alList = new ArrayList<>();
        alList.add(Place.Field.ADDRESS);
        alList.add(Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
        alList.add(Place.Field.NAME);
        alList.add(Place.Field.ID);
        Autocomplete.IntentBuilder autoCompleteIntentBuilder = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, alList);
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strQuery)) {
            autoCompleteIntentBuilder.setInitialQuery(strQuery);
            autoCompleteIntentBuilder.setCountry("IN");
        }
        startActivityForResult(autoCompleteIntentBuilder.build(mActivity), LOCATION_SEARCH_REQUEST);
```

gradle dependency is

```
        implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.0.0'
```

[image]

Comment: not per day please read this document https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage-and-billing

Comment: Choose custom plan for your acount

Comment: can you suggest which and how to select plan?

Comment: sorry I have no idea.

Comment: Kindly file a support case here https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support to open a personalized communication channel and also for the support team to further check your project and give available options for you.